# three20 TTTableViewController drag to refresh: no error screen on no connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

My app heavily relies on the three20 TTTableViewController. I am currently working on error handling, specifically related to connectivity issues. I have found that if I load with createModel that it displays a nice error msg about the status of connectivity. However, when I do a drag to refresh... it does not show me the error screen when there is no connection. Besides creating a separate datasource and model (local) and doing createModel again, is there a better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can cache the results for how long you want to by modifying the cache settings in your model's load function, as such:

```
request.cachePolicy = TTURLRequestCachePolicyDefault;
request.cacheExpirationAge = 3600 * 60;
```